# Show legend in chart

Tags: asp.net, charts, mschart, legend

I am using [Microsoft Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Graph), and I have top Legend displayed at the top in a pie chart. Which property is used to show or hide the legend of a pie chart?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just do the following.

```
Legend leg = new Legend();
Chart1.Legends.Add(leg);// This will show all legends.
```

Actually you have to create a legend object, set its different or desired properties like font, etc., and then add it to the chart.